# Extending/modifying generated entities in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am creating a REST api service for a mysql database. I've generated classes using IntelliJ's persistence tool. It does a pretty good job.

There are some quirks to the schema that I am working with. The users want the endpoints to be accessible by another property other than the "id" primary key column.

Ex: `/object/<name property>' versus`/object/`.

Here is the catch though. The schema can change. The name property is not going anywhere though so I can safely assume that will always be on the object.

I've learned that you can use Superclasses to force these generated entites to have custom properties without affecting the database schema. I dont want to make a model change in the generated entity and have that update the database table layout as it is not my database.

I have a class called Animal.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "animals", schema = "xyz123", catalog = "")
    public class AnimalEntity extends AnimalSuperclass {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private String description;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 80)
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 255)
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            RoleEntity that = (RoleEntity) o;
            return Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
                    Objects.equals(name, that.name) &&
                    Objects.equals(description, that.description);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {

            return Objects.hash(id, name, description);
        }
    }
```

I have to manually add extends AnimalSuperclass. Which is fine for now. Eventually I am going to try to generate these using .xmls on runtime.

Then I have this superclass..

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class AnimalSuperclass implements Serializable  {
        private String testMessage;
        private String name;
        private Integer id;

        @Transient
        public String getTestMessage() {
            return this.testMessage;
        }

        public void setTestMessage(String id) {
            this.testMessage = testMessage;
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is force the `@Id` annotation to be on the name property from within the superclass. Something like this..
        @MappedSuperclass
        public class AnimalSuperclass implements Serializable  {
            private String testMessage;
            private String name;
            private Integer id;

```
        @Transient
        public String getTestMessage() {
            return this.testMessage;
        }

        public void setTestMessage(String id) {
            this.testMessage = testMessage;
        }

        @Basic
        @Id
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 15)
        private String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        private void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        @NaturalId
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        private Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        private void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

**How do I go about doing that?** Currently this throws an error when I hit the endpoint: `{"cause":null,"message":"Id must be assignable to Serializable!: null"}`

Java is not my first language so I am not an expert by any means. But from what I've read, its not possible to override subclass properties from the superclass. Is there a better way to approach this, maybe by using `RepositoryRestConfiguration`? I am using `PagingAndSortingRepository` to serve these entities. I cannot extend the entities and use my superclass as a child as that creates a `dType` property in the schema and I cannot alter the table layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard link between the request and your entity. In your repository you can write methods that can query the data that is brought it from the request.

For example if they are requesting a name you can do something like

```
Page<AnimalEntity> findByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
```

in your Repository. Spring will take care of the rest and then you can call this in your controller.

```
@Service
public class AnimalService {
  @Autowired
  private AnimalEntityRepository animalRepo;


  public Page<AnimalEntity> findAnimal(String name) {

    Page<AnimalEntity> animals = animalRepo.findByName(name, new PageRequest(1,20));

    return animals;
  }
}
```

One thing to mention is that depending on how you configured Hibernate when sending an entity back to the client and the entity is seralized you might get an failed to lazy initialize error. If that is the case your entities will have to be converted to a POJO (plain old java object) and that sent back.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How would the repository method findbyName look in its final form? I tried adding those in but the /animal/<name> endpoint still looks for a integer id.

Comment: I should mention I am using HATEOAS so I only have models and repositories. No custom controllers apart from this one we have created. 

I understand the workflow of how this works now. But when I try to use my browser to go to `/animal/cheetah`, spring still thinks I am using the id and gives me this error: `Provided id of the wrong type for hello.models.AnimalEntity. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String`. If I set a breakpoint in that findAnimal function, it never reaches that code. I am positive the name cheetah is populated.

Comment: Can you update your OP of the client snippet that is sending the data and the server code that is handling the request?

Comment: Nvm, @locus2k updated with `@PathVariable` instead of `@RequestParam` and it  works. How do I retain the previous format though with the pagination?